# my !important "no-animate" class isn't making an exception for my navigation bar

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

my web app has an ng-animate transition applied to it in the style.css:

```
.ng-enter, .ng-leave {
position: absolute;
top: 8em;
left: -100%;
width: 100%;
transition: left .5s;
}


.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
left: 0%;
}

.ng-leave {
left: 0%;
}

.ng-leave-active {
transition: left .5s;
left: 100%;
}
```

Unfortunately, this has resulted in it being applied to my navigation bar as well, which results in it causing a weird glitch where, whenever I log in or out, the links slide across the view for a half a second before appearing in the proper place:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mainApp" ng-cloak>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=UnifrakturMaguntia" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prociono" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://tappedout.net/tappedout.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

    </head>
    <body id="background" ng-controller="mainController">

        <div class="ourNav no-animate">            
            <div class="logo">Deckster</div>

            <div>
                 <i class="fa fa-bars fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
            </div>

            <ul id="links">
                <li ng-if="loginStatus !== true">
                    <div>
                        <a class="active" ui-sref="home" ui-sref-active="active">Home</a>
                    </div>    
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <a class="active" ui-sref="cardSearch" ui-sref-active="active">Card Search</a>
                    </div>    
                </li>
                <li ng-if="loginStatus == true">
                    <div>
                        <a class="active" ui-sref="deckBuilder" ui-sref-active="active">Deck Builder</a>
                    </div>    
                </li>
                <li ng-if="loginStatus == true">
                    <div>
                       <a class="active" ui-sref="deckCollection" ui-sref-active="active">Deck Collection</a> 
                    </div>    
                </li>
                <li ng-if="loginStatus == true">
                    <div class="logout">
                        <a class="active" ng-click="logout()" ui-sref-active="active">Log Out</a>
                    </div>    
                </li>                                                      
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div ui-view class="view-container" ></div>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="./node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="./node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>

        <script src="./dropDownMenu.js"></script>
        <script src="./app.js"></script>
        <script src="./service.js"></script>
        <script src="./controller.js"></script>
        <script src="./cardSearchController.js"></script>
        <script src="./deckBuilderController.js"></script>
        <script src="./deckCollectionController.js"></script>
        <script src="./homeController.js"></script>
        <script src="./loginSuccessController.js"></script>
        <script src="http://tappedout.net/tappedout.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried to add the class "no-animate" in hopes of having the links not slide around, but it hasn't helped despite being important.

```
  .no-animate {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
 }
```

what do I need to do to make my "ourNav" class not be effected by transitions? Note that I'm using bootstrap, so I don't know if that could be causing it.

edit: I don't know if the z-index might make a difference, but the styling has the navigation bar at z-index: 1, so it can drop down as a hamburger menu when viewed on tablet or mobile:

```
.ourNav {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:not(.no-animate)` in your css to exclude those element wich have `no-animate` class. Like this:

```
.ng-leave:not(.no-animate) {
  transition: left .5s
}
```

In this case the `.ng-leave.no-animate` wont have the transition effect

Edit:

```js
window.onclick = () => {
 const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
 for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  const element =  elements[i];
  element.classList.add("black");
 }
}
```

```css
.element {
 background-color: blue;
}

.element:not(.not-me) {
 transition: background-color 2s;
}

.element.black {
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="element" > me </div>
<div class="element not-me" > not-me </div>
<div class="element" > me </div>
```

Look what happens on click. The elements with the `not-me` class don't get a transition. There is no need to use `!important`, just watch for the specifity. Hope it helps

Comment: I tried adding `:not(.no-animate)` to these transitions:

`.ng-enter:not(.no-animate), .ng-leave:not(.no-animate) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8em;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    transition: left .5s;
  }
  

  .ng-enter.ng-enter-active:not(.no-animate) {
    left: 0%;
  }
 
  .ng-leave:not(.no-animate) {
    left: 0%;
  }
 
  .ng-leave-active:not(.no-animate) {
    transition: left .5s;
    left: 100%;
  }

  .no-animate {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
 }`

unfortunately, I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @Codenami I updated the answer with a more descriptive example

Comment: I read your example, and tried it by adding "not-me" as a class to the navigation div: `<div class="ourNav not-me">`, and adding :not(.not-me) to each of the transitions such as `.ng-enter:not(.not-me), .ng-leave:not(.not-me) {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8em;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    transition: left .5s;
  }` .
unfortunate, the nav bar links are still affected by the transition.

Comment: I've updated the original post to include the ".our-nav" css.